# How can I create profile links for users with Branch.io?

Tags: branch.io

So I have configured all the basics for branch to get universal links set up between my website, app, and App Store. I also have installed the iOS SDK, and am looking for a way to create profile links for each user. I found this [documentation](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-advanced-features) that does a great job of showing how. However, I am not sure how my specific case fits in.

At the top under Create Content Reference you can create a link with

```
BranchUniversalObject.init(canonicalIdentifier: "content/12345")
```

and

```
branchUniversalObject.getShortUrl(with: linkProperties)
```

This works, but further down the page there is another section called Create Deep Link.

That is where the shortURL is created but with properties given for a Link Reference. I am a bit confused on how my specific use case fits in here. Allow me to give an example:

User signs up on a social networking app, user is assigned a unique id. I want to also give each user a link to their profile just like any other social networking app has. Once clicked, it acts just like a universal link but when the app is installed, it opens the users profile. Which of these methods do I need to follow?

Another thing, I tried creating a deep link where the canonicalIdentifier is "users/unique_id" and I didn't provide any link properties, will this accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

Yes, your deep-linking to specific profile use-case can be achieved through Branch links. To begin with, first, you have to configure what the link data will look like which the below code does -

```
let lp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
lp.channel = "facebook" // feel free to customize this
lp.feature = "sharing"
lp.campaign = "content 123 launch"
lp.stage = "new user"
lp.tags = ["one", "two", "three"]

lp.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: "http://userProfile/url")
lp.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: "http://userProfile/url")
lp.addControlParam("$android_url", withValue: "link to playStore URL")

lp.addControlParam("profile", withValue: "UserProfile/123")
```

The first 5 are basically `analytical tags` that will help you view the Installs, Clicks, and Opens on Branch Dashboard based on these values. The remaining are the link data which is what you can use to build the routing logic.

The code to retrieve the short URL will look like this -

```
branchUniversalObject.getShortUrl(with: linkProperties) { (url, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            print("Got my Branch link to share: (url)")
        } else {
            print(String(format: "Branch error : %@", error! as CVarArg))
        }
    }
```

Once you have received the short link any time you open the app through this link, it'll pass back to you the associated link data in the SDK initialization callback. You can then leverage the profile or any other key-value pair as per your preference to redirect the user.